# C#: How to correctly execute auto-generated methods from web service with a timeout in an async method?

Tags: c#, async-await, wsdl, webservice-client

I need to call some methods from a web service, specified in WSDL. VisualStudio created the corresponding methods for me, including async variants. The documentation specifies (different) timeouts for those methods, some of them could take several minutes. So what is the best way to implement this?

I have two approaches, but I'm not sure which one is better, or if I should do something completely different:

Variant 1: use generated async method and task.Wait instead of await:

```cs
public async Task<ResultType> MyMethod1Async()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(60000);
    Task<ResultType> task = MyWebService.getSomeObjectAsync();
    task.Wait(cts.Token);
    return task.Result;
}
```

Variant 2: execute generated synchronous method in Task.Run:

```cs
public async Task<ResultType> MyMethod2Async()
{
    CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    cts.CancelAfter(60000);
    Task<ResultType> task = Task.Run(
        () => MyWebService.getSomeObject(),
        cts.Token);
    return await task;
}
```

Comment: The first option blocks the thread, which you shouldn't do in an async method. Awaiting is the right choice.

Comment: But isn't wrapping a synchronous method in Task.Run also something to avoid?

Comment: Awaiting is good, but yes, in this case you are awaiting something that will not release the thread back to the pool until it's done anyway. You might as well run it async-less.

Comment: Well, async-less is not an option, I can't block the UI for several minutes... Do I understand that corretly that when the timeout occurs, the calling method will stop waiting and an OperationCanceledException is thrown, but the thread will continue anyway?

Comment: Doesn't VS/svcutil generate methods with cancellation tokens?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Maybe I did something wrong, but it only created async methods without cancellation tokens. Should there be a setting for that?

Comment: I further tested this. None of the variants really work. Variant 1 stops waiting, but as mentioned before, the getSomeObject method keeps running anyway. And variant 2 doesn't abort the task at all - from the docs: "A cancellation token allows the work to be cancelled **if it has not yet started**."

Comment: It has been a while since I fiddled with WCF. [You can configure timeouts in the binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding).

Comment: @PauloMorgado Thanks for the hint about the timeouts in the binding. This at least gives me the possibility for a maximum timeout per service. I guess these are not per-call, right? Like, when I have 2 parallel calls, I cannot just set a different timeout for each of them, can I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither option will do what you want.

Variant 1 will block on `task.Result` regardless of any timeout. Variant 2 will not be cancelled once the method has started running

If the async task does not support cancellation, the best you can do is to return to the caller when the timeout is reached, and let the task continue in the background, any eventual result will be ignored. For example:

```
    public async Task<ResultType> MyMethodAsync<T>(TimeSpan timeout)
    {

        var task = SomeAsyncMethod<ResultType>();
        var timeoutTask = Task.Delay(timeout);
        var completedTask = await Task.WhenAny(task, timeoutTask);

        if (completedTask == timeoutTask)
        {
            // Handle timeout somehow
            throw new TimeoutException("...");
        }

        return task.Result;
    }
```

This is obviously not appropriate for compute bound tasks, and if it is possible to use real support for cancellation it should be used.

Comment: Beware that this pattern cancels the invocation on the caller side, but not the operation itself.

Comment: @PauloMorgado I guess that's what he meant with letting the task continue in the background. Apparently there's no way around that, except for timeouts in the binding as you mentioned in your comment above.

Comment: Yes. I think that's what @JonasH meant. Just making it clear.